# Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin.  Embedded error: Opening resource

Tags: maven, osgi

I have been having issues building an OSGi project with maven. I started getting a weird error.

I suppose some resource is corrupted. but I have no idea of which one. I have tried to delete .m2/repository. but the problem persists.
Any ideas of how to correct this problem?

```
[ERROR] An internal error occurred
java.io.IOException: Opening resource
at aQute.lib.osgi.AbstractResource.getLocalBytes(AbstractResource.java:35)
at aQute.lib.osgi.AbstractResource.write(AbstractResource.java:46)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Jar.writeResource(Jar.java:445)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Jar.write(Jar.java:224)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Jar.write(Jar.java:192)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:362)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:264)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:255)
at    org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '�'
at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2519)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2501)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2430)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2383)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2781)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Processor.formatArrays(Processor.java:1273)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Processor.warning(Processor.java:116)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.replace(Macro.java:144)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.process(Macro.java:71)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.process(Macro.java:58)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.process(Macro.java:53)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.process(Macro.java:964)
at aQute.lib.osgi.PreprocessResource.getBytes(PreprocessResource.java:25)
at aQute.lib.osgi.AbstractResource.getLocalBytes(AbstractResource.java:31)
... 26 more
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin

 Embedded error: Opening resource
 Conversion = '�'
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Trace
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:412)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:264)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Opening resource
at aQute.lib.osgi.AbstractResource.getLocalBytes(AbstractResource.java:35)
at aQute.lib.osgi.AbstractResource.write(AbstractResource.java:46)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Jar.writeResource(Jar.java:445)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Jar.write(Jar.java:224)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Jar.write(Jar.java:192)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:362)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '�'
at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2519)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2501)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2430)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2383)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2781)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Processor.formatArrays(Processor.java:1273)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Processor.warning(Processor.java:116)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.replace(Macro.java:144)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.process(Macro.java:71)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.process(Macro.java:58)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.process(Macro.java:53)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Macro.process(Macro.java:964)
at aQute.lib.osgi.PreprocessResource.getBytes(PreprocessResource.java:25)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.AbstractResource.getLocalBytes(AbstractResource.java:31)
... 26 more
```

As requested, the maven-bundle-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>org.opennaas.extensions.idb.*;version="${project.version}"</Export-Package>
                    <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: That Conversion = '�' looks suspicious, I'd check the POM is latin1 encoded and ensure the path in front of the .m2 directory has no non-ascii characters in it.  Please edit your question to include the maven-bundle-plugin's configuration

Comment: apparently the problem was encoding. But not of the pom.xml but of the persistence.xml (and possible other resource files). I resaved all my resources and now it works ok.

Comment: Please file a bug and ask for better diagnostics on github/bndtools/bnd

Comment: @santiagozky, it's probably a good idea to add your previous comment as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @earcam. I need to wait to be able to accept my own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in fact an encoding issue. Probably with the persistence.xml file. I resaved all my text files under the resources directory and it started working again

Answer (score 2):

Running into the same error I'd like to share my findings which might be helpful until the diagnostic message is improved.

I got the error when I added

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

to my bundles pom.xml. One of the files in my resources directory had an encoding issue, and by using the

```
<includes>
```

directive with one file after the other I was able to figure out which one it was.

Comment: got a similar error when trying to copy a certificate (keystore.jks) to a bundle. The way I solved it was to disable filtering by setting:

<filtering>false</filtering>

What was happening was the plugin was trying to read the certificate as text and converting the certificate to UTF-8, not good :)

Comment: The reason is because filtering load the file and check the content inside it, the simple way is disable filtering if not required or better add special **exclusion pattern** with tag 

`<nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
</nonFilteredFileExtensions>`

reference: [maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html) or for a more generic filter approach: [maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)